# Concat a number's value in a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I am running test with Capybara on Ruby. I got an error for this code

```
pos = rand languages.size
# advanced_search.adv_language_labels[pos].click 
script = "$('label[for*='lang']:eq(" + pos.to_s + ")').click()"
page.execute_script script
```

How can I get this 'pos' value to the script so that I can run with execute_script command? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you're generating looks like this:

```
$('label[for*='lang']:eq(5)').click()
```

Note there's an internal pair of single quotes that's closing out the `label` path before you mean to. You need to escape those.

```
$('label[for*=\'lang\']:eq(5)').click()
```

Comment: thank you. I found another solution for this too: %{$('label[for*="lang"]:eq(#{pos})').click()}